# Android App Development call doesnt call full USSD code

Tags: android, adt, ussd

My app currently does not produce the final "#" at the end of AT&T's USSD code for checking data use (Which is supposed to be *3282#)

Here is my code:

```
public void callATT(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "*3282#"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Everytime it calls it just calls "*3282"

Please help me,

Thanks in advance

-Tucker

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I did not test it, but should work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("*3282#")));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Uri USSDToCallableUri(String ussd) {
    String uriString = "";

    if(!ussd.startsWith("tel:"))
        uriString += "tel:";

            for(char c : ussd.toCharArray()) {

                if(c == '#')
                    uriString += Uri.encode("#");
                else
                    uriString += c;
            }

    return Uri.parse(uriString);
}
```

Then Set This :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, USSDToCallableUri(USSDCodeHere));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use this method....

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
                    String ussd = "*123"+ encodedHash;
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri
                            .parse("tel:" + ussd)));enter code here
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this . Tell me it works or not

```
 String phone = "*3282#";
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
 startActivity(intent);
```